# Families of genus zero curves vs Family of deformations of $\mathbb{P}_k^1$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, schemes, moduli-space

Suppose I am looking to classify isomorphism classes of connected, compact, projective curves of genus zero.  We usually start this moduli problem by considering a scheme $S$ and families of genus zero curves over $S$ up to isomorphism. Here $\mathbb{P}_1^k$ is projective over the algebraically closed field $k$. $S$ is assumed to be an affine $k$-algebra.  I will define such a family over $S$ to be a smooth, proper morphism $\pi: X \to S$ of schemes of relative dimension $1$.

Now, we know genus zero curves over $\operatorname{Spec} k$ are isomorphic to the projective line $\mathbb{P}_k^1$.

Here is my question: Is such a family equivalent to a family of deformations of $\mathbb{P}_k^1$?  That is, for the family $\pi: X \to S$,  does there exist a point $s \in S$, such that $X_s \cong \mathbb{P}_k^1$

Comment: Yes. I am assuming the curves to be projective.

Comment: Yes. $S$ should be a $k$-algebra.

Comment: Yes, that can be assumed

Comment: And apparently $k$ is algebraically closed? Do you also assume $\operatorname{char}k=0$? Sorry for the load of questions, but all of these assumptions make the question a *lot* simpler. Could you include these in the body of your question?